# Why doesn't the clearInterval() works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clearinterval

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm having problems with this script.
it's part of a web game and the script is suppose to refresh the page until the player wins or loses.
for some reason it doesn't stop refreshing, I put an alert function to check if the functions works, and i get the alerts but it's still  continue refreshing the page.
what am i doing wrong?

```
var t;

$(document).ready(function () {
    intervals();
});
function intervals() {
    t = self.setInterval('refreshData()', 10000);
}
function youWin() {
    var f = $('#status:contains("YOU ARE THE WINNER!")');
    if (f.length > 0) {
        alert("YOU ARE THE WINNER!");
        t = clearInterval(t);
    }
}
function youlose() {
    var f = $('#status:contains("You lost!")');
    if (f.length > 0) {
        alert("You lost!");
        t = clearInterval(t);
    }
}
function refreshData() {
    $('#ajaxGame').load('RefreshCurrentPlayerServlet #ajaxGame');
    youWin();
    youlose();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix the reference to `self` and fix the `.load()` call.

`.load()` is asynchronous so it does not complete before you call `youWin()` and `youLose()` right after it.  You need a completion function so you can check winning or losing after the `.load()` completes successfully.

`refreshData()` should be structured like this:

```
function refreshData() {
    $('#ajaxGame').load('RefreshCurrentPlayerServlet #ajaxGame', function() {
        youWin();
        youlose();
    });
}
```

You also should change this:

```
t= self.setInterval('refreshData()',10000);
```

to this:

```
t = window.setInterval(refreshData, 10000);
```

I don't see that `self` was even defined so that could have also been causing your problem and you should use the function reference directly rather than put in a string.

And, as a cleanup issue, you should change both occurences of this:

```
t = clearInterval(t);
```

to this:

```
clearInterval(t);
```

Here's a cleaned up version of the code that also eliminates global variables and unnecessary function definitions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = window.setInterval(function() {
        $('#ajaxGame').load('RefreshCurrentPlayerServlet #ajaxGame', function() {
            youWin();
            youlose();
        });
    }, 10000);

    function youWin()  {
        if ($('#status:contains("YOU ARE THE WINNER!")').length) {
            alert("YOU ARE THE WINNER!");
            clearInterval(t);
        }
    }

    function youlose() {
        if ($('#status:contains("You lost!")').length) {
            alert("You lost!");
            clearInterval(t);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's still refreshing for 2-3 times but it eventually stops.
I didn't realize that the load() function was not done.
Thanks.

Comment: @user1090448 - Do you see any errors on the javascript error console or the debugger console?  The interval will keep going until it gets an error or until you stop it.

Comment: No, no errors, not in the console and also not in the net-beans debugger(no servlet error).